# Using `count` with scopes that have a select method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a scope --

```
scope :most_stock, -> {
    joins(:stock_keeping_units).
    select("items.*, count(stock_keeping_units.id) AS stock_keeping_unit_count").
    group('items.id').
    order('stock_keeping_unit_count DESC').
    where('stock_keeping_units.sold = FALSE')
}
```

When I run `Item.most_stock`, everything works fine and dandy.

However, when I run `Item.most_stock.count`, I get the following error -

`PG::SyntaxError: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "AS" LINE 1`

The generated SQL Query is -

`SELECT COUNT(items.*, count(stock_keeping_units.id) AS stock_keeping_unit_count) AS count_items_all_count_stock_keeping_units_id_as_stock_keeping_u, items.id AS items_id FROM "items" INNER JOIN "stock_keeping_units" ON "stock_keeping_units"."item_id" = "items"."id" AND "stock_keeping_units"."deleted_at" IS NULL WHERE "items"."deleted_at" IS NULL AND (stock_keeping_units.sold = FALSE) GROUP BY items.id  ORDER BY stock_keeping_unit_count DESC`

A work around is to use `length`

I'm curious to know what `count` didn't work here or is it something that should ideally work?